# connecting mysql to visual web developer

Tags: .net, mysql, connection, visual-web-developer

is there a way to connect mysql to visual web developer like it's connected to visual studio.

*notes*: i have mysql community server, i have the .net connector , visual web developer 2010 sp1.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think offhand that the ODBC connector (or the .NET one) would do. The .NET connector is here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html

I haven't used it with visual web developer myself, but it should work.

Comment: Oh, and how to use with VS is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio.html